# Getting data using button

Tags: php

I make simple page using `input[type="button"]`. My problem is, that I want to delete data in database using this `type="button"`, but I'm confused about in using this. I used this button for some reason.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function del()
            {
                window.location.href='recdelete.php';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    ......
    ......
    while ( $field = $count->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) )
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$field->fld1.'</td>';
        echo '<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="del()"></input></</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

In my `recdelete.php` I dont know how to delete this certain record. Can you give me some pointers on this. Thank you.

Comment: I would start by adding a [CSRF-token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Comment: If I'm right, then `</input>` is not needed here. Also I see, that only thing you will achieve with that code is redirect. You can specify  in this question by what criteria you would want to delete records and what data do you have on this page with this button. Then we could suggest something.

Comment: @Eugene,in my database example i have this idno,name,familyname,and i want to delete that idno by clicking the delete button,this record in my database is displayed in table which has delete button.after clicking the delete button.It will go to the recdelete.php for confirmation(ok and cancel).

Comment: @jemz then I would go with @blasteralfred suggestion. Passing the `idno` and using it to remove the record could solve the problem. By additional use of `jQuery` for example `$.ajax` method you could make it more usable also. In ajax response for example check if record was deleted then remove it also from table.

Comment: @Eugene,i tried to put alert before window.location but it shows the string inside the id attribute..i want this example idno "123" after clicking delete button it will go to the confirmation page,do you really want to delete idno 123?by the way is PDO can handle urlencode?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the field name in the value of the delete button, read that through the JavaScript, and append that to the URL. You might benefit from using jQuery and Ajax for things like this. You might also benefit from taking a programming class or two to learn problem solving skills.

Answer (score 0):

Give the button a specific id which has relation to the data displayed in that row. You may then cusomize the delete URL like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function del(id)
 {
   window.location.href='recdelete.php?id='+id;
 }
</script>
```

by making

```
<input type="button" id="specificid" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="del(this.id)"></input>
```

Comment: Example would be better if you place the number in `id` attribute instead of the `specificid`. I guess, that person would get it faster.

Comment: @blasterafred,i tried to put alert before window.location,it display the word in id attribute.